# Use a function to ouptut elements of a dataframe

Tags: r

I was asked in a project to create a function that outputs the price of a stock on a user-specified date and writes an error message if the date is not included in the data. I got

last part of a project, I need to create a function that output the price of a stock from a previous database that I created depending on the date the user entered. That database is named H and the date column in named dat.

I tried to do that code but that doesn't work

```
facebook=function(d) {
  if (d %in% dat) p=H$Price[H$Date=='d']
  print(p)
  else print("The date provided is not included in the data.")
}
```

Does anyone already work on something similar ? I need either a code or a good structure to advance on my project. Thank your for helping me

Comment: shouldn't it be `if(d in H$dat)`?

Comment: 1) What @AllanCameron said; 2) The `'d'` in `p=H$Price[H$Date=='d']` is a string literal, remove the quotes; 3) Without `{` and `}` only one of the instructions after the `if` will be executed; 4) If you want a message printed, it is recommended to use, well, `message`; 5) Remove all occurrences of `p`; 6) Why call a function `facebook`? That's a very specific thing and the function seems to be general purpose. Other name, please.

Comment: Thank you for the help and the quickness; 1) I got an error when I associate if and in that is why I used %in% instead but I think it is quite the same (or maybe not)  2) I corrected my code but I got a big problem which I think is because the variable of my function is a date and no a number that is the first time for me and I had a hard time handle it  3)my H dataframe is a bunch of facebook stock prices that is why I called it facebook

Comment: My new code is that one :
facebook=function(d) {
  if (d %in%  H$Date) p=H$Price[H$Date==d]
  else p=c("The date provided is not included in the data.")
  print(p)
} 
The structure seems much better but it doesnt recognize my d variable that is a date